# HTML/PHP Require Error

Tags: php, html

I am slowly working on a personal project to be able to write a web page that only uses one page.  I am running into an error in one directory of my web page but the same code works in other places.

Errors:

> Warning: require(MainClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\CSSFiles\index.html on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'MainClass.php'
>   (include_path='../Testproj/PHPClasses') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\CSSFiles\index.html on line 3

Code:

```
<?php
    set_include_path("../Testproj/PHPClasses");
    require "MainClass.php";
    $Controller = new MainClass();
?>
```

Can Anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Do you know what version of PHP you are using?

Comment: @BlueBoy shouldn't matter. *(PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7)* http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: *"No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\CSSFiles\index.html on line 3"* yet you're using `"../Testproj/PHPClasses"` - Plus, an example from the manual `set_include_path('/usr/lib/pear');`

Comment: Does it work if you set your include path to an absolute location?

Comment: Make sure that you have set reading permissions for all users to that files @ducky

Comment: Ah ok, thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: I believe your problem is your directory slashes.  Linux style directory separators in Windows file system.  Use `'..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Testproj' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHPClasses'` instead for something more cross platform.

Comment: @Crackertastic I tried that but it didn't fix the problem.  I have the same code in the `\Testproj` directory and it works fine, I also have it in the `\Testproj\PHPClasses` folder and it works.  Just won't work in the `\Testproj\CSSFiles` Folder.

Comment: @Dave Chen     I have not tried to set the path as an absolute path since I am just running off of Xampp for testing purposes.

Comment: Does XAMPP have read permissions to that folder? If you paste this link, `C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\CSSFiles\index.html` into your windows explorer and it works then I would suspect is it because xampp can't read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you do not need another 'Testproj' in your include path so it should be `..\PHPClasses`

However, I do not recommend overwrite include path by calling `set_include_path`, because in your example you exclude standard libraries from the path. I would simply use `require "../PHPClasses/MainClass.php";` without  `set_include_path(...)`

Comment: That did it, i was thinking I could use the same code for every page, but got errors in different folders.  Thanks fr the help.